# Expand Magic Words from MediaWiki extension

Tags: php, mediawiki

I need to expand the magicword {{CURRENTPAGEE}} from a mediawiki extension:

```
<extension>{{CURRENTPAGEE}}</extension>
```

but the macro is not expanded before passing it to the extension's argument, is there any way to get the current page url before passing it to the extension? Or to get the calling url from inside the extension code?
Thanx a lot!

Comment: While I didn't find the answer I've found a possible solution: from the extension code you can declare "global $wgTitle" to get the title (with spaces) of the calling page.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `Parser`’s method `recursiveTagParse`, as described by ["How do I render wikitext in my extension?" in the MediaWiki manual](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aTag_extensions#How_do_I_render_wikitext_in_my_extension.3F), or to get the current page’s title you can indeed use the global `$wgTitle` or, which is better, the parent frame (passed as fourth parameter to the callback), which has public attribute `$title`.